# Azure Function App code deployment issue through Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Function App already created and I want to deploy a python function with Azure DevOps pipeline. The issue is that the pipeline runs without errors but the function is not created. Instead, in the App Files of the Function App, I see that in the `wwwroot` folder there is the `ImpervaWAFCloudSentinelConn` folder with all its contents as well as a default `host.json`.

Here is the pipeline I run:

```yaml
trigger:
  - none

resources:
  - repo: self

variables:
  azureSubscription: "<my-service-connection>"
  functionAppName: "<my-function-app-name>"
  resourceGroupName: "<my-rg>"


stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build Function App
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build Code
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '3.8'
              addToPath: true
              architecture: 'x64'
          - bash: |
              pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./src/ImpervaWAFCloudSentinelConn/requirements.txt
          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/ImpervaWAFCloudSentinelConn'
              archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              artifactName: drop
  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy Code to Function App
    jobs:
      - job: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy Code to Function App
        pool: DevOps VMSS Agents
        steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              artifactName: drop
              targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
            inputs:
              connectedServiceNameARM: $(azureSubscription) # string. Alias: azureSubscription. Required. Azure Resource Manager connection.
              appType: 'functionAppLinux' # Required. App type.
              appName: $(functionAppName) # Required. Azure Functions App name.
              resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroupName)
              package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
              runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.8'
              deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
```

The application that I'm trying to deploy on the function app is the one mentioned in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/data-connectors/imperva-cloud-waf-using-azure-functions).

The file structure of the git repository is the following:

```
- pipelines/ 
     -- azure-pipelines-src.yaml 
- src/ 
     -- ImpervaWAFCloudSentinelConn/ 
         --- host.json 
         --- proxies.json 
         --- requirements.txt 
         --- ImpervaWAFCloudSentinelConnector/ 
            ---- __init__.py 
            ---- function.json 
            ---- state_manager.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have the following file structure:

```
pipeline/
├─ azure-pipeline-src.yaml
src/
├─ ImpervaWAFCloutSentinelConnector/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ function.json
│  ├─ state_manager.py
├─ host.json
├─ proxies.json
├─ requirements.txt
```

What I need to do is to create a deployment slot in the Function App and deploy it there. In the end you have to swap with the default slot.

Here is the pipeline that worked for me:

```yaml
trigger:
- none

variables: 
  azureSubscription: <service-connection-or-subscription-name>
  functionAppName: <function-app-name>
  resourceGroup: <resource-group-name>
  slotName: <slot-name>

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.8'
        addToPath: true
        architecture: 'x64'

    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
        fi
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./src/requirements.txt
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: "Archive files"
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src"
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        artifactName: 'drop'

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool: DevOps VMSS Agents
    steps:
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          buildType: 'current'
          artifactName: drop
          targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
        inputs:
          connectedServiceNameARM: $(azureSubscription)
          appType: 'functionAppLinux'
          appName: $(functionAppName)
          package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
          runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.8'
          deploymentMethod: 'auto'
          deployToSlotOrASE: true
          resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroup)
          slotName: $(slotName)
      - task: AzureAppServiceManage@0
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
          Action: 'Swap Slots'
          WebAppName: $(functionAppName)
          ResourceGroupName: $(resourceGroup)
          SourceSlot: $(slotName)
          PreserveVnet: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy the Function from this **[Imperva Cloud ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/data-connectors/imperva-cloud-waf-using-azure-functions)** and the **[url](https://aka.ms/sentinel-impervawafcloud-functionapp)** mentioned in this ARM template for the Function Trigger code files does not contain local.settings.json file, Thus it is causing the Function app to not read the function.  As **local.settings.json** file is necessary for the Function app deployment even if it contains local settings. You can download the Function code from the URL and add local.settings.json in the root level Refer below:-

**local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=valleystrg129;AccountKey=xxxxxm9GXkEbQyVIUtd15vxxxxE7Bxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
    }
  }
```

*Make sure you add a storage account Connection string in AzureWebJobsStorage*

**My Function code locally with below format:-**

[image]

I sent this code to Azure repository and deployed the Function via Azure DevOps pipeline like below:-

**My Azure DevOps repository:-**

[image]

**Selected below option:-**

[image]

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxx35a6cbaf'

  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'valleyfunc769'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.6'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.10 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Function is visible and got deployed successfully like below:-**

[image]

Comment: 2 host.json files are present by default that would not cause a issue. But it did worked for me with above method by adding local.settings.json and following the yaml script and steps I have given above